# Invalid credentials (Failure) for oauth while using token generated through JAVA code

Tags: java, oauth

I am trying to use oauth to access my inbox, I always get invalid credential error when I use token generated using my JAVA code. I am using IMAP and passing oauth token to get authenticated. But when I generate token using python and use the same in my code, it works fine and fetch emails from my Inbox.

Here is the code snippet using IMAP:

```
public static IMAPSSLStore connectToImap(String host,
                                          int port,
                                          String userEmail,
                                          String oauthToken,
                                          String oauthTokenSecret,
                                          OAuthConsumer consumer,
                                          boolean debug) throws Exception {
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
   props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH");
   props.put(XoauthSaslClientFactory.OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP,
             oauthToken);
   props.put(XoauthSaslClientFactory.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET_PROP,
             oauthTokenSecret);
   props.put(XoauthSaslClientFactory.CONSUMER_KEY_PROP,
             consumer.consumerKey);
   props.put(XoauthSaslClientFactory.CONSUMER_SECRET_PROP,
             consumer.consumerSecret);
   Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
   session.setDebug(debug);

   final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
   IMAPSSLStore store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, unusedUrlName);
   final String emptyPassword = "anonymous";

   store.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);
   return store;
 }
```

Here is the error log -

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.3.3
1
2
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: enable SASL
DEBUG: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH
3
4
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 122.179.85.133 kn10if6680532igc.14
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! kn10if6680532igc.14
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap.googlemail.com, user=me@mydomain.com, password=<non-null>
IMAP SASL DEBUG: Mechanisms: XOAUTH
IMAP SASL DEBUG: SASL client XOAUTH
A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH
+ 
IMAP SASL DEBUG: challenge:  :
IMAP SASL DEBUG: callback length: 1
IMAP SASL DEBUG: callback 0: javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@d1e832
IMAP SASL DEBUG: response: GET https://mail.google.com/mail/b/me@mydomain.com/imap/ oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_token="1%2Furn42qGc5mpD3BwVvJMzeVkHl_9iVRCZvaSOYmKNH5A",oauth_consumer_key="mydomain.com",oauth_timestamp="1329301212",oauth_nonce="629121335212995",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="7O1YHXywiqOX8XzSAd%2BzbmDoBVw%3D" :
R0VUIGh0dHBzOi8vbWFpbC5nb29nbGUuY29tL21haWwvYi9wZXRlckBhMm9tb2JpbGUuY29tL2ltYXAvIG9hdXRoX3NpZ25hdHVyZV9tZXRob2Q9IkhNQUMtU0hBMSIsb2F1dGhfdG9rZW49IjElMkZ1cm40MnFHYzVtcEQzQndWdkpNemVWa0hsXzlpVlJDWnZhU09ZbUtOSDVBIixvYXV0aF9jb25zdW1lcl9rZXk9ImEyb21vYmlsZS5jb20iLG9hdXRoX3RpbWVzdGFtcD0iMTMyOTMwMTIxMiIsb2F1dGhfbm9uY2U9IjYyOTEyMTMzNTIxMjk5NSIsb2F1dGhfdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIixvYXV0aF9zaWduYXR1cmU9IjdPMVlIWHl3aXFPWDhYelNBZCUyQnpibURvQlZ3JTNEIg==
5
DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
A2 EXAMINE INBOX
A1 NO [ALERT] Invalid credentials (Failure)
A2 BAD Unknown command r5if6689112igo.50
A3 LOGOUT
* BYE Logout Requested r5if6689112igo.50
A3 OK Quoth the raven, nevermore... r5if6689112igo.50
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: A2 BAD Unknown command r5if6689112igo.50;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A2 BAD Unknown command r5if6689112igo.50
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:820)
    at com.a2o.service.collaboration.common.XoauthAuthenticator.getMessages(XoauthAuthenticator.java:238)
    at com.a2o.service.collaboration.common.XoauthAuthenticator.main(XoauthAuthenticator.java:205)
```

Is there any way to generate token properly from JAVA code. My actual requirement is to generate token using my iPad client and fetch emails using that token in my server. Any help is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

we have used http://pastebin.com/kwcZQcvj to create token and secret.